# Webcam freezes when I send Serial data

Tags: c++, opencv, serial-port, webcam, freeze

Im using openCV with an arduino. My code tracks objects just fine and when a object is found it sends the arduino a message to send out an HIGH signal.

The thing is my code works and I am able to see the webcam feed and track desired objects. But the problem is that when I send serial data from my code (computer) to an arduino UNO the webcam freezes. I'm pretty sure that i'm interrupting the camera feed somehow, but i'm using different USB plugs on the same computer.

The camera is 30Hz, 1.3MP. So i'm thinking that i am interrupting some byte packages from the webcam by sending randomly out signals from the USB to the arduino. Which freezes the webcam feed.

I'm using this for serial communication to the arduino from my openCV c++ code.

link:[The SerialClass im using](http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows)

And im using similar code for the tracking to this tutorial if that does matter

link:[OpenCV youtube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RS_uQGOQIdg)

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Some input would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How are you sure the program is sending the signal to Arduino, not webcam?

Comment: I specify the COM port for the Arduino in the c++ code. 
Serial* SP = new Serial("\\\\.\\COM4");